# How to expand a list row when we tap on it in listview

Tags: android, listview

In my app I have a Custom listview with some textviews and Image view like following image.
[image]

My requirement is when we tap on a list row it should expand and when tap on it again or tap on any other row  it should collapse. Expanded row should be like this
[image]

Contents of the expanded row is dynamic, some times no data and some times more values. It should look like in the 2nd image. Please give a solution for this.

Comment: There are millions of solutions to be found on google. I found [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html). Maybe it'll help

Comment: Use expandable listview... It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Expandable ListView bydefault has two levels. First is called the "Group View" and the second level is called the "Child View". You can simply achieve by making use of the Custom Adapter sample from the very first link I have provided.

here are few links which will get you started,

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

http://www.techienjoy.com/android-expandable-list-dynamically-created-example.php

**EDIT 1**

To make only child expanded at a particular time, add this,

```
explist.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {


        for(int i=0; i<myExpAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            if(i != groupPosition) {
                explist.collapseGroup(i);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: First of all thanks. As far as I know in expandable listview, we can expand more than one row at a time. I need only one row should be populated at a time. when we tap on any other row it should be collapsed and the current row should be expanded.

Comment: I will edit my answer for this. Please wait.. It is possible actually.

Comment: Check my Edit. This is how I achieved it.